# Male/Female Classification with Matlab- About Finding Mean Image

Tags: image, matlab, classification, mean

I am working on a project which is about pattern (male/female)classification with matlab.I have a problem, I need your help, please.

My program should find mean images of datasets. First dataset is women,second dataset is men. So first mean image has to look like a woman and second a man.I have different datasets which all have format of jpeg. I am trying different datasets for my program to check if it is working but when I use different datasets I can not see true mean images all the time, for ex:

They are mean images from a dataset:

[image]

But when I use another dataset my mean images are like this, they have no meanings, I mean they dont look like face:

[image]

What can be the reason for this? I should work with different datasets. Please help.
    `

```
filenamesA = dir(fullfile(pathfora, '*.jpg'));
Train_NumberA = numel(filenamesA);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Finding Image Vectors for A

imagesA= [];
for k = 1 : Train_NumberA

    str = int2str(k);

    str= strcat(str);

    str = strcat('\',str,'b','.jpg');
    str = strcat(pathfora,str);

    imgA = imread(str);
    imgA = rgb2gray(imgA);
    [irowA icolA] = size(imgA);
    tempA = reshape(imgA',irowA*icolA,1);   % Reshaping 2D images into 1D image vectors
    imagesA = [imagesA tempA]; % 'imagesA' grows after each turn 

    imagesA=double(imagesA);
end`


`%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Calculate the MEAN IMAGE VECTOR for A

mean_vectorA= mean(imagesA,2); % Computing the average vector m = (1/P)*sum(Tj's)    (j = 1 : P)
mean_imageA= reshape(mean_vectorA,irowA,icolA);   % Average matrix of training set A
meanimgA=mat2gray(mean_imageA);
figure(1);
imshow(rot90(meanimgA,3));`



-------------------------------------And same for dataset B (male)
```

Comment: It's impossible to say, because you haven't shown any code.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have shown now.

Comment: Ok, you should do some debugging yourself first.  For a start, you need to simplify your code (all the stuff to do with creating a filename is irrelevant, for instance).  You should then inspect intermediate variables, to make sure they're what you expect.

Comment: I am really new at matlab. So I need what you mean more clear. For example why creating a filename is irrevelant? What is the right way?

Comment: what purpose does `str = strcat(str);` serve? Why not just `str = strcat(pathfora, '\', int2str(k), 'b.jpg');` or `sprintf('%s\%db.jpg', pathfora, k)`?

Comment: Yes, I got it.That's just stuff.I am changing the code for different datasets,because all images in different datasets have different names.So I have corrected it but the result does not change.I can not take the mean images true.

Comment: Hi Mr. Ozer, would you please give me your codes or at least more information about your work? I have a similar project and wanted to know about your idea. this is my email: khodabandeh@ce.sharif.edu. Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a 3D matrix to store the images. I also cleaned up the code a bit. Not tested.

```
filenamesA = dir(fullfile(pathfora, '*.jpg'));
Train_NumberA = numel(filenamesA);

imagesA = [];

for k = 1:Train_NumberA
    imgA = imread(strcat(pathfora, '\', int2str(k), 'b', '.jpg'));
    imgA = rgb2gray(imgA);

    imagesA = cat(3, imagesA, imgA);
end
```

`double` command moved out of loop.

```
imagesA = double(imagesA);
```

Calculate the mean over the 3rd dimension of the `imagesA` matrix to get the mean 2D image.

```
meanimage_A = mean(imagesA, 3);
```

Convert to grayscale image.

```
meanimgA = mat2gray(meanimage_A);
```

I think `rot90` is not needed here...

```
figure(1);
imshow(meanimgA, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a 3D array or cell array of images instead of reshaping 2D images into single rows of a matrix.  The reshaping is unnecessary and can only add bugs.

If all your images are the same size, you can use a multidimensional array: [Matlab documentation on multidimensional arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-86528.html)

Otherwise, use a cell array: [Matlab documentation on cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html)

Comment: Could you please give example? I am a new user at matlab.

Comment: I added links to the appropriate Matlab documentation.